# Can I delete C:\inetpub\temp\appPools?

Tags: iis, windows-7

Quite sure I'm not using IIS, in this case, what is the usefulness of the folder **inetpub** ?
Can I delete **C:\inetpub\temp\appPools** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would contain your IIS application pools.  If you're not using IIS, you don't need it, so it's safe to delete (as is the whole of the `inetpub` folder, FWIW).

Comment: Thanks, simple professional computer running with Windows 7. No IIS. Any idea why this folder has been created please ?

Comment: @Elwyn It comes with several types of Visual Studio tools and Windows SDKs, etc. Same with SQL Express.